# An integral with integration span going to $0$, inside a limit...

Tags: integration, limits, taylor-expansion

Let's say I need to calculate this one, it is inside a limit, I saw the result is: $x^2 + o(x^4)$

$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} -2\int_{0}^{\ x^{2}} \cos t^{2} \, dt$

Obviously, has to do with McLaurin but...

What I need to do, in this scenario? The stopping degree of the expansion $(x^4)$ has to do with the entire exercise and is not relevant.

Comment: Just use $\cos{t^2}=1-t^4+O(t^8)$ and integrate from there.

Comment: $1- x^8 + o(x^{16})$ ?

Comment: 1 substitution at a time.

Comment: can't understand :/ ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x<1$, by mean value theorem there exists $\psi$ such that $0\leq \psi\leq x^2$ and
$$\int_{0}^{\ x^{2}} \cos t^{2}dt=\cos\psi^2 (x^2-0)=x^2\cos\psi^2$$
but $\cos x^4\leq \cos\psi^2\leq 1$ and $x^2\cos x^4\leq x^2\cos\psi^2\leq x^2$, so
$$x^2\cos x^4\leq \int_{0}^{\ x^{2}} \cos t^{2}dt\leq x^2$$
taking the limit then [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) shows the limit is $0$ as $x\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

This one is damn simple. If $x$ is small such that $0< x^{2}<1$ then obviously $0<\cos t^{2}<1$ for $0<t<x^{2}$ and hence we can see that $$0<\int_{0}^{x^{2}}\cos t^{2}\,dt<x^{2}$$ By Squeeze Theorem the integral above tends to $0$ as $x\to 0$ and hence the desired limit is $0$. There is no need to use any Taylor series for cosine function.